# Programmatic UI: don't call super.loadView but do call super.viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

This question pertains to programmatic-only apps that don't use nib files where the storyboard has been removed and the window is created and given a root view in the app delegate. Some of the accepted answers I've read here appear to conflict with Apple's documentation, so tell me if this is correct:

When creating a `UIViewController`, the methods that create its foundation should be placed in `loadView` **without** calling `super.loadView`:

```
override func loadView() {

    // build something
    buildSomething()

}
```

And the methods that make the final touches should be placed in `viewDidLoad` **with** calling `super.viewDidLoad`:

```
// view did load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // arrange something that requires it be built first
    arrangeSomething()

}
```

Or should `super.viewDidLoad()` be called only in special situations? If so, what are they?

Comment: "Some ... answers ... conflict with Apple documentation." ... We obviously can't comment on those unless you edit your question to include references to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct, that if you implement `loadView` you should not call `super`. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) says:

> Your custom implementation of this method should not call `super`.

But if you implement `viewDidLoad`, you should always call `super`.

Comment: Follow-up: when doing everything programmatically, UIWindow should only be called once in app delegate, correct? And then when creating a UIViewController, Apple says to assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property, meaning create a UIView the bounds of the screen and attaching that to self.view?

Comment: @sconewolf - Yep. See "Creating the View Programmatically" in legacy [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html). My only refinement on your comment is that setting the bounds of the `view` really belongs to whomever presented it (e.g. in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, not in `loadView`. A view controller doesn't know whether it is full screen or not. Whomever presented it does.

Comment: the concepts make perfect sense and so I took out the super.loadView and now my UIPageViewController is acting weird. Would you mind looking at (and freely editing if you would also be so kind) this public Gist I just created? https://gist.github.com/sconewolf/22f5767193df9148ca15c894ffcce4de